# PowerShell outputs XML data on the end of execution

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-4.0

When I parse an xml file by reading it with `Get-Content` and casting it to XML and then insert a new node into it, PowerShell echoes the content of the newly created node. Why is PowerShell doing that?

```bsh
$proj = [xml](Get-Content $project.AbsolutePath)

$element = $proj.CreateElement("Version");
$element.InnerText = "1.0.0";
$proj.Project.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($element);

Write-Host "OK"
```

After that there is really no other code than that. But it still echoes the following text:

```
OK
#text
-----
1.0.0
```

I have tried to set the variable `$element` to `$null`, just in case there is some weird global variable I should not touch. I even told the script to exit on the end of the script.
When I bypass the execution of the insertion of the new node, no additional text is written to the end of the script.

Comment: [AppendChild()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netframework-4.8) returns the new node, which PowerShell is displaying as it doesn't know what else to do with it.  Something like this will prevent that: `$proj.Project.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($element) | Out-Null`

Comment: in addition to what `boxdog` mentioned, the _sequence_ is out of order because `Write-Host` goes DIRECTLY to the screen, while the output stream is delayed slightly to see if there is more to be grouped with it. direct = `right freaking NOW`. indirect = `slight delay`.

Comment: PowerShell delays output to be able to summarize under the same heading, this has the side effect that the order isn't always kept. Otherwise do as suggested by @boxdog.

Comment: Thank you guys! You halped me a lot!
@boxdog if you could write this as an answer, i could give you an upvote and mark the thread as closed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AppendChild()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netframework-4.8) returns the new node, which PowerShell is displaying as it doesn't know what else to do with it. Something like this will prevent that:

`$proj.Project.PropertyGroup.AppendChild($element) | Out-Null`